# How to build and run unit test Visual Studio 2017 ASP.net .NETCoreApp Version 1.1 on linux using travis-ci

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, travis-ci

I get an error when `dotnet restore ./solution.sln` is called on travis-ci.

error MSB4019: The imported project "/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/1.0.4/Sdks/Microsoft.Docker.Sdk/Sdk/Sdk.props" was not found.

my `.travis.yml`

```
language: csharp
dotnet: 1.0.4
mono: none
dist: trusty
env: DOTNETCORE=1  # optional, can be used to take different code paths in    your script

install:
    - dotnet restore ./solution.sln --verbosity detailed

script:
    - dotnet test --configuration Release --verbosity detailed
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After same research on a local ubuntu machine, i worked it out :)

with that `.travis.yml` file my simple projects with 2 unittest projects build and runs all unit tests fine using travis-ci.

```
language: csharp
dotnet: 1.0.4
mono: none # is not needed
dist: trusty # Ubuntu 14.04.5 image
env: DOTNETCORE=1  # optional, can be used to take different code paths in your script
addons:  
 apt:
   packages:
   - libcurl3 # needed for 'dotnet restore'

install:
   - dotnet restore ./solution.sln

script:
#    - dotnet build ./solution.sln --configuration Release
    - find . -name *.xUnitTests.csproj -exec dotnet test {} --configuration Release \; # build and run xunit tests
```